# Swift: Compiler's conversion from type to optional type

Tags: swift, option-type

It looks like compiler automatically converts a type into an optional type when needed, even though there is no inheritance relationship here.

Where in the documentation is this behavior specified?

```
func test(value: String?) {
    // String passed in is now an optional String instead.
    print(value ?? "")
}

// Pass an actual string
test(value: "test")
```

Comment: I believe it's the same compiler magic behaviour that allows us to assign a value of type `Wrapped` to an `Optional<Wrapped>` (`let foo: String? = "foo"` or `let foo: String? = someConcreteStringInstance`), something not possible for just are regular `enum` with, say, an associated value of type `Wrapped`.

Comment: I also think that is a special treatment of optionals by the compiler. The "Swift Tour" shows the example `var optionalString: String? = "Hello"` but I don't know if that wrapping is explicitly documented somewhere.

Comment: Also observed here https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/08/17/implicitly-converting-functions-to-return-optionals/: *"if you pass a non-optional value to a function argument that expects an optional, it will get automatically converted into an optional by the compiler."*

Comment: Also from https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/08/17/implicitly-converting-functions-to-return-optionals/: *"Incidentally, if you run -dump-ast on a call that requires a conversion from regular type like Int to an optional, you’d see inject_into_optional implicit type='Int?'."*

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the Swift compiler, but looking at how SIL parses expressions, it will at some point attempt a (LLVM) [`dyn_cast<...>`](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa) of an expression [into the type `InjectIntoOptionalExpr`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/SILGen/SILGenApply.cpp#L2962), which is an [expression type described as _"The implicit conversion from T to T?"_](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/Expr.h#L2757). Coupled with @MartinR:s comments, the answer to your question is most likely ...

Comment: ... _"by means of non-explicitly documented compiler "magic" (/expression parsing)"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is actually explicitly documented in a well-hidden corner of the `docs` folder of the Swift github repo.

Citing [swift/docs/archive/LangRef.html](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/50f053a8f9874b5fe28f7f6ef0090fc26acdb99b/docs/archive/LangRef.html#L1266) [changed some formatting; **emphasis mine**]:

> #### Types
>
> ```
> type ::= attribute-list type-function
> type ::= attribute-list type-array
>
> ...
>
> type-simple ::= type-optional
> ```
>
> Swift has a small collection of core datatypes **that are built into
>   the compiler**. Most user-facing
>   datatypes are defined by the standard library or declared as a user
>   defined types.
>
> ...
>
> #### Optional Types
>
> Similar constructs exist in Haskell
>   ([Maybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html)),
>   the Boost library
>   ([Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)),
>   and C++14
>   ([optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)).
>
> ```
> type-optional ::= type-simple '?'-postfix
> ```
>
> An optional type is syntactic sugar for the library type `Optional<T>`.
>   This is a `enum` with two cases: `None` and `Some`, used to represent
>   a value that may or may not be present.
>
> Swift provides a number of special, builtin behaviors involving this
>   library type:
>
> - **There is an implicit conversion from any type `T` to the corresponding optional type `T?`**.
>
> ...

See the `htmlpreview.github.io` rendering of the HTML for easier overview of the docs than the .html source:

- http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/archive/LangRef.html
- [htmlpreview of the `LangRef.html` at July 25 2017](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/50f053a8f9874b5fe28f7f6ef0090fc26acdb99b/docs/archive/LangRef.html#L1266) (from which state the information above has been cited)

---

Now, this is me speculating, but the reason why this is not very publicly available (and also not entirely up to date; placed in the *archive* sub-folder, and still using the old `None` and `Some` cases rather than `none` and `some`, respectively) is probably because the Swift team (no longer?) see a reason for general Swift users to know details regarding the compiler "magic" associated with the very special type `Optional`, but rather focuses on the use cases and grammar (in the context of the Swift language and not its compiler) of `Optional`.

Comment: Bravo, you found it! – It is nice to have an explicit reference.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! There are quite a few goodies in that archived language reference, so I'm somewhat surprised it's been lumped into the archive with the motivation [_"... historical-interest-only docs"_](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/de15f8a3b52db12f1ed461a1f3cf5d441b9d7042), but maybe much of the information (which is still "relevant") has been duplicated elsewhere.

Comment: That link shows HTML source code. I wonder if there is an easy way to *render* the page as HTML.

Comment: @MartinR I did a failed try to just access the raw html. A quick googling found a SO thread (naturally :) which describes [this that `htmlpreview.github.io` can be used](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/archive/LangRef.html). As to my previous comment regarding the archiving of that .html, I realize much of it is naturally present in the current [language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AboutTheLanguageReference.html) (although seemingly some things are not).