# Assign a Type directly to a Type wrapper in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a generic type wrapper which allows you to annotate a value as "absolute" or "relative":

```
enum Value<Wrapped> {
    case .absolute(Wrapped)
    case .relative(Wrapped)
}

func printValue(_ value: Value<Int>) {
    switch value {
    case .absolute(let value): print(value)
    case .relative(let value): print(value + 10)
    }
}

printValue(.absolute(5))    //5
printValue(.relative(5))    //15
```

Is there anyway to define `Value<Wrapped>` in such a way that you can directly assign an instance of `Wrapped` and it will infer the correct case? For example:

```
printValue(5)    //5
printValue(.relative(5))    //15
```

Swift Optionals appear to do this:

```
func printValue(_ value: Optional<Int>) {
    switch value {
    case .none: print("nil")
    case .some(let value): print(value)
    }
}

printValue(5)    //5
```

Can I achieve this same behaviour in my enum? Or is `Optional` achieving this through compiler magic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Compiler's conversion from type to optional type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302816/swift-compilers-conversion-from-type-to-optional-type) – optionals have special compiler support.

Comment: +1 for dupe mark: quoting the linked thread, _"There is an implicit conversion from any type `T` to the corresponding optional type `T`?"_ – this is builtin behaviour specifically available to the `Optional` type (which is generally described as a two-case `enum`, but, w.r.t. many features, a creature of its own).

Comment: I hadn't seen that answer. It does sound like a duplicate. Although, that question is asking specifically about `Optional`. The fact that `Optional` achieves what I'm looking for using special compiler support doesn't necessarily mean that it can't be achieved by other means; However unlikely that might be...

Comment: You can make `printValue(5)` compile by adopting the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol (example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39160889/1187415). But that won't help for `printValue(someIntVariable)`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `Optional` has special language support. You can still have a `printValue` overload that just calls out the other one.

```
func printValue(_ value: Int) {
    printValue(.absolute(value))
}
```

Comment: Yeah, problem is that I have a method which takes many of these as parameters, so I'd have to overload every combination: `printValues(a: Value<Int>, b: Value<Float>, c: Value<Double>)`