# How to make type optional if and only if it is not so?

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I need to write some `foo` function like so:

```
func foo<T>(_ v : T) -> R
{
    // ...
}
```

Here `R` should be `T` if `T` is an optional type and `T?` if it is not so. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: A side note for the interested: What you want here is the way the [Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org/) language works in the standard case: An option is expressed as a union type of `Null` (which only contains the value `null`) and some other type `T`. That is written `T | Null` -- a type which contains either the value `null` or a value of type `T`. In your case you would write an option of an option like this: `(T | Null) | Null` which is equivalent to and simplified by the compiler to just `T | Null`. Ceylon is very pretty and interesting, check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in Swift. You are better off declaring the function with optional argument and result and just handling it as an optional wherever you use this function:

```
func foo<T>(_ v : T?) -> T?
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can overload `foo` to specify the different two cases.

```
// Dummy protocol for this example to allow a concrete dummy T instance
// return in case the provided T? argument is nil (in your actual
// implementation you might have other logic to fix this scenario).
protocol SimplyInitializable { init() }
extension Int : SimplyInitializable {}

func foo<T>(_ v : T) -> T? {
    print("Non-optional argument; optional return type")
    return v
}

func foo<T: SimplyInitializable>(_ v : T?) -> T {
    print("Optional argument; Non-optional return type")
    return v ?? T()
}

let a = 1        // Int
let b: Int? = 1  // Int?

foo(a) // Non-optional argument; optional return type
foo(b) // Optional argument; Non-optional return type
```

A method with an optional `T` parameter (`T?`) may always be called by a non-optional argument `T`, but there will be an implicit conversion done (backend); hence if an overload with a non-optional parameter `T` is available, it will take precedence in overload resolution when invoked with a non-optional argument `T`, as there will be no need of an implicit conversion to `T?`.

For details regarding the implicit conversion from a `T` to `T?`, see:

- [Swift: Compiler's conversion from type to optional type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302816/swift-compilers-conversion-from-type-to-optional-type)

> Swift provides a number of special, builtin behaviors involving this
>   library type:
>
> - There is an implicit conversion from any type `T` to the corresponding optional type `T?`.